# Prism ServiceLocator GetInstance and MEF

Tags: c#, prism, mef

I'm trying to use Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ServiceLocator and MEF. Interface IServiceLocator defines method GetInstance with two parameters. First parameter is  serviceType and second paremeter is key.

I have two classes which implement interface IMyInterface and they have Export attribute:

```
[Export(typeof(IMyInterface)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Class1 : IMyInterface 
{}

[Export(typeof(IMyInterface)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Class2: IMyInterface 
{}
```

I want to get instance of Class1 via Prism ServiceLocator GetInstance method:

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(typeof(IMyInterface),"Key");
```

But I have no idea how and where should be "key" defined. I tried to define key in export attribute:

```
[Export("Key1",typeof(IMyInterface)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Class1 : IMyInterface 
{}

[Export("Key2",typeof(IMyInterface)), PartCreationPolicy(CreationPolicy.Shared)]
public class Class2: IMyInterface 
{}
```

When I call method GetInstance with key parameter

```
ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance(typeof(IMyInterface),"Key1");
```

I get Microsoft.Practices.ServiceLocation.ActivationException (Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type IMyInterface, key "Key1"). Does anybody know how can be the export key defined?
Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Prism uses `MefServiceLocatorAdapter` to adapt MEF's `CompositionsContainer` to the `IServiceLocator` interface. This is the actual code that is used by it to get your part:

```
protected override object DoGetInstance(Type serviceType, string key)
{
    IEnumerable<Lazy<object, object>> exports = this.compositionContainer.GetExports(serviceType, null, key);
    if ((exports != null) && (exports.Count() > 0))
    {
        // If there is more than one value, this will throw an InvalidOperationException, 
        // which will be wrapped by the base class as an ActivationException.
        return exports.Single().Value;
    }

    throw new ActivationException(
        this.FormatActivationExceptionMessage(new CompositionException("Export not found"), serviceType, key));
}
```

So as you can see, you're exporting and calling `GetInstance` correctly. However, I believe your service locator isn't set up correctly, and that's why you're getting this exception. If you're using Prism's `MefBootstrapper` to initialize your application, this should already be done for you. Otherwise, you'll need to use this code to initialize it:

```
IServiceLocator serviceLocator = new MefServiceLocatorAdapter(myCompositionContainer);
ServiceLocator.SetLocatorProvider(() => serviceLocator);
```

Comment: Thanks, initialization of service locator works. But when I also use import many attribute [ImportMany(typeof(IMyInterface))]
        public IEnumerable<IMyInterface> List { get; set; } List property is alwasy emtpy.

Comment: It's empty because `[ImportMany(typeof(IMyInterface))]` will only import parts that were exported without a contract name.

Comment: And is there any way how to import parts with importmany attribute that were exported with a contract name? Because in one part of my application I need to work with collection of classes which implements given interface and in another part I need to work with concrete class which I get via ServiceLocator.Current.GetInstance.

Comment: You have several options here: 1. Use two export attributes - one with a contract name and one without. This way you'll be able to import them either with a contract name, which will give a single instance, or with no contract name, which will give all instances. 2. Export the parts [with metadata](http://mef.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Exports%20and%20Metadata) and select the specific instance according to its metadata as you've defined when exporting it.

Comment: Trying to figure out what to do in prep for unit testing MEF controlled objects.  In my case I had to additionally call myCompositionContainer.ComposeExportedValue<IServiceLocator>( serviceLocator );